# Is it easy to use friendly urls with Modx? If so, what is the process?

Tags: .htaccess, url, permalinks, modx

I would like to structure my sites pages in a similar manner to the way it is done in WordPress... That is, parent pages with children pages that show the path in the url.

For example:

www.example.com/parent/child/grandchild

Is this possible in Modx, and if so, is it practical to do / easy to do?

Comment: Seriously man, did you even try? https://www.google.com/#q=modx+friendly+urls

Answer (score 0):

This is [almost] fully documented here: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/using-friendly-urls

basically, edit your .htaccess & change some system settings.

The gotchas are;

- clearing the cache, do this after and make sure you clear your browser cache as well
- you control the actual url by editing the "Resource Alias" in each resource
- if you want your urls to end in a slash, i.e. http://www.example.com/parent/child/grandchild/ you also need to change the content type [system->content types] of the HTML extension to "/". For no slash, leave it blank.

Comment: You shouldnt have to touch the htaccess? Changing the system setting should be enough.

Comment: @KristianSandström - Not true. You have to uncomment the section from the .htaccess-file and you may also have to define the base-alias.